# AutoScrolling to the bottom of div not working in android with Html

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am using the following function which auto scrolls to the bottom of the div.It works fine when i test it in Google chrome and other browser but when i test it in android phone its not working

This is the javascript function

```
 function displaysender()
{
    var msg = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML+='<b>Me</b>: '+msg+'<br><br>';
    var element = document.getElementById("display");

    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;


}
```

following code is the html part

```
   <div id="display" style="width:85%;height:340px;overflow:scroll"></div>
   <form>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="b">

        <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" data-theme="b" style="float:right; width:60%"></textarea>

    <a href="" style="float:left"  data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="e" onclick="displaysender();sendToBackend();">Send</a>
   </div>
</form>
```

Any time of help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having the same problem T_T

Answer (score 0):

You cant also try

```
window.scrollTo(0,element.offsetTop);
```

Comment: thnx for replying, i will try and let you know

Comment: Are you sure that there arent multiple divs with the same id "display" ?

Comment: where is displaysender() called ?

Comment: code updated..but this code is working fine in browser .I am not understanding why its not working on the phone

Comment: android 2.3 had problems with overflow:scroll. Did you try removing that ?

Comment: Hmm, I am sorry, cant think of a reason why it is not scrolling. A while back, I had this issue where a div block had zero size and zero top offset. It was due to not clearing a float.